# Android - How can I merge text with image?

Tags: android

Do you know if it's possible to merge an input text with a image?

Comment: Down voted probably because you haven't shown any attempt at the problem

Comment: i agree bad phrased question imply lake basic knowledge in android or bad english lang

Answer (score 1):

may be you mean image view like this example you can add an icon to the list

The classic Android ListView is a plain list of text—solid but uninspiring. Basically, we
hand the ListView a bunch of words in an array and tell Android to use a simple built-in
layout for pouring those words into a list.
However, we can have a list whose rows are made up of icons, icons and text, check
boxes and text, or whatever we want. It is merely a matter of supplying enough data to
the adapter and helping the adapter to create a richer set of View objects for each row.
For example, suppose we want a ListView whose entries are made up of an icon,
followed by some text. We could construct a layout for the row that looks like this, found
in res/layout/row.xml in the FancyLists/Static sample project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/selection"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This layout uses a LinearLayout to set up a row, with the icon on the left and the text (in
    a nice big font) on the right.
    However, by default, Android has no idea that we want to use this layout with our
    ListView. To make the connection, we need to supply our Adapter with the resource ID
    of the custom layout shown previously:

```
 public class StaticDemo extends ListActivity {
    private TextView selection;
    private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
    "sit", "amet",
    "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
    "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
    "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
    "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.row, R.id.label,
    items));
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
    int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
    }
    }
```

This follows the general structure for the previous ListView sample. The key difference
here is that we have told ArrayAdapter that we want to use our custom layout
(R.layout.row) and that the TextView where the word should go is known as R.id.label
within that custom layout.
NOTE: Remember that to reference a layout (row.xml), use R.layout as a prefix on the base
name of the layout XML file (R.layout.row).
The result is a ListView with icons down the left side; in this example, all the icons are
the same, as shown in Figure 13-1.

[image: figure 13-1]

Comment: i uploaded the image which might take a time to appear